# JSon Flickr Feed link to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, feed

I am connecting to a flickr feed and showing the images on my page.

It works fine but what I click on any of the images it links to the page where the images comes from.

What I what it to do is to link to the actual image instead of the whole page.

Here is the current code:

```
<script>$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images").wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");



            if ( i == 20 ) return false;
          });
        });</script>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the url for the static image server in the feed which seems to be in the `<media:content>` field in the url attribute.
      `<media:content url="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7031/6404754477_f2338d2484_b.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="683" width="1024"/>`

The above example comes from this feed in flickr:  http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=china&lang=en-us&format=rss_200

You should be able to just parse out the url from each individual item in the feed.  In a JSON feed,
it looks like the static photo is in `item.media.m` which points to the medium sized photo.  If the larger sizes are available, they can be accessed as well.

So you might change your code to look like:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images").wrap("<a href='" + item.media.m + "'>  </a>");



        if ( i == 20 ) return false;
      });
```

Comment: And where would I add this code to? <media:content> field in the url attribute.
<media:content url="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7031/6404754477_f2338d2484_b.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="683" width="1024"/>

Comment: Its not javascript code, it's the xml in the rss feed.  You'll have to query with jquery as you do now for the img src attribute.

Comment: ok, I noticed in your updated example you are getting the JSON feed.  I'll update.